# Did Amin al-Husaini say, "slaughter Jews wherever you find them"?

Tags: quotes, antisemitism, amin-al-husseini

[Mohammed Amin al-Husseini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amin_al-Husseini) (1897-1974) was a Palestinian Arab nationalist and Muslim leader in Mandatory Palestine. He was appointed as the grand Mufti of Jerusalem in 1921 by the British High Commissioner to shill for the British Colonial Empire. But in 1935, he rebelled against the British in support of the 1936–39 Arab revolt in Palestine.

According to [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Haj_Amin_al-Husseini) he is alleged to have said:

> Arise, o sons of Arabia. Fight for your sacred rights. Slaughter Jews wherever you find them. Their spilled blood pleases Allah, our history and religion. That will save our honor.

The Wikiquote page references a 2011 [Frontpage magazine article](http://www.frontpagemag.com/fpm/111632/voices-palestine-haj-amin-al-husseini-frontpagemagcom) article as source. That article merely says it was a "March 1, 1944 broadcast" without reference. It gives [a broken link](http://www.frontpagemag.com/Articles/ReadArticle.asp?ID=4738) as the source of the article.

Did Amin al-Husaini say, "slaughter Jews wherever you find them"?

Comment: The Internet Archive has a saved version of the Frontpage article, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150115031624/http://archive.frontpagemag.com/readArticle.aspx?ARTID=21014). I searched the page but could not find the terms "Arise, o sons of Arabia" so... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DavePhD You're right. I mis-typed my comment; I meant the *source* of the Frontpage article, which was included in the post as "[a broken link](http://www.frontpagemag.com/Articles/ReadArticle.asp?ID=4738)."

Comment: Please don't use the comments to give us your view on the question. It's not what they are for.

Comment: @oddthinking - is there a specific reason you omitted the "Mufty of Jerusalem" part of clarifying who he was? If not i'll edit it in as it seems important context

Comment: @user5341: Not a specific reason. I wanted to include enough context to (a) distinguish him from others with a similar name, (b) remind readers who had heard of the name but couldn't place him who he was, (c) provide a way to learn more about him if the reader (like me) had never heard of him, and (d) reassure readers with modern sensibilities that this wasn't someone recent who needed to be ousted or boycotted, but was a long-dead leader from a time and place where such an outrageous statement would almost be mundane.

Comment: @Oddthinking - your last paragraph is not quite right. The outrageousness of the statement among Muslims pre-1900 is much higher than before Mufti's reign - while occasional local persecution occurred, Jews [were treated *relatively* less-genocidally by Islamic countries despite discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_under_Muslim_rule); before 1850 (and even before 1910 or so) with some exceptions. One can argue that [Mufti was actually the driving force behind the anti-Semitic Arab/Muslim sentiment](http://www.jstor.org/stable/25834622?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: @user5341: Okay, I accept that. Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

He would regularly broadcast in Arabic from Berlin, and these transmissions were relayed to other axis radio transmitters for the Arab world to hear.

In March of 1944, speaking on Berlin radio he said:

> Arabs! Arise as one and fight for your sacred rights. Kill the Jews wherever you find them. This pleases God, history, and religion. This saves your honor. God is with you.

Some sources say March 1st others say March 4th.

Sources:

[Asia and the Americas](https://books.google.com/books?id=nIgeAAAAMAAJ&q=march%201944%20%22Kill%20the%20Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&dq=march%201944%20%22Kill%20the%20Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLtZ_75OPSAhXDOiYKHaS1An0Q6AEIODAH) (1946)

[The Central European Observer](https://books.google.com/books?id=RQMLAQAAMAAJ&q=march%201944%20%22Kill%20the%20Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&dq=march%201944%20%22Kill%20the%20Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLtZ_75OPSAhXDOiYKHaS1An0Q6AEINDAG) (1946) (says "March 1, 1944")

[Mufti of Jerusalem; the story of Haj Amin el Husseini](https://books.google.com/books?id=GNptAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&dq=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIkejH5-PSAhXI7iYKHRhYCdoQ6AEINDAG) (1947) (says "12.30 hours on 1st March, 1944")

[Behind the Silken Curtain](https://books.google.com/books?id=cxj1od1JWLYC&q=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22%20march&dq=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22%20march&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH9_Gg6ePSAhVIQCYKHRXEAbsQ6AEIMzAG) (1947) (says "on March 4, 1944, when the United States Monitoring Service heard him broadcast")

[Phylon: Atlanta University Review of Race and Culture, vol. 9, page 319](https://books.google.com/books?id=G84KAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Jews+wherever+you+find+them%22+march&dq=%22Jews+wherever+you+find+them%22+march&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSnevm6uPSAhUGOSYKHbMtBLcQ6AEIJzAD) (1948) (alternative [JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/271959?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents))(says "March 4, 1944, over Radio Berlin again")

[Reconstructionist](https://books.google.com/books?id=KKsSAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&dq=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIkejH5-PSAhXI7iYKHRhYCdoQ6AEIHjAB) (1948)

[Congressional Record](https://books.google.com/books?id=GAviqA8idSQC&q=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22%20march&dq=%22Jews%20wherever%20you%20find%20them%22%20march&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjci6m_6uPSAhUBWSYKHcmFAF84ChDoAQgrMAQ) (1948)

According to [The Mufti and the Fuehrer: the rise and fall of Haj Amin el-Husseini](https://books.google.com/books?id=TZZtAAAAMAAJ&q=dare%20to%20Judaize%20palestine%20while%20arabs%20are%20still%20alive&dq=dare%20to%20Judaize%20palestine%20while%20arabs%20are%20still%20alive&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNzOGJ8ePSAhUGSiYKHRwRCCUQ6AEIHjAA) a more complete quotation is:

> No one ever thought that 140,000,000 Americans would become the hands of the Jews....How would the Americans dare to Judaize Palestine while the Arabs are still alive?...The wicked American intentions toward the Arabs are now clear, and there remain no doubts that they are endeavoring to establish a Jewish empire in the Arab world. More than 400,000,000 Arabs [?] oppose this criminal American movement.... Arabs! Rise as one and fight for your sacred rights. Kill the Jews wherever you find them. This pleases God, history, and religion. This saves your honor. God is with you.

More recent sources indicate that the primary source is:

> Weekly Review of Foreign Broadcasts, F.C.C. [Federal Communications Commission], No. 118 3/4/44, Near and Middle East,” United States National Archives, College Park, Record Group 165, MID, Regional File, 1922-44, Palestine, entry 77, Box 2719, folder 2930

In other words, the primary source is stored at this location: https://www.archives.gov/dc-metro/college-park

Particularly, see at https://www.archives.gov/research/holocaust/finding-aid/military/rg-165.html#Intelligence the listing of 3335 boxes under:

> Formerly Security-Classified Intelligence Reference Publications ("Regional File") Received From U.S. Military Attaches, Military and Civilian Agencies of the United States, Foreign Governments, and Other Sources, 1922-1944 (Entry 77)

Comment: @Mohammad the article you linked to doesn't indicate the US spread a lot of lies, or even any lies, about the enemy.

Comment: Did he say it in English? If not could you also quote the original text?

Comment: @ChrisW No, he didn't say it in English.  His broadcasts were in Arabic.  No, I do not have the original Arabic.

Comment: @ChrisW "All the Axis radio stations were placed at his disposal, and Arabic programmes were daily beamed to every country with a Moslem population from Berlin, Rome, Bari, and later Athens" https://books.google.com/books?id=GNptAAAAMAAJ&q=%22,+Ban,+and+later+Athens.+Important+pronouncements+by+the+ex-Mufti+himself+were%22&dq=%22,+Ban,+and+later+Athens.+Important+pronouncements+by+the+ex-Mufti+himself+were%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidyfTE0eXSAhXFKyYKHcRWDmIQ6AEIGjAA

Comment: Thank you. It's not that I don't believe you. I only asked because many of the [questions about quotes](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A2703+%5Bquotes%5D) that I've answered on this site are mistranslated or taken out of context.

Comment: Do these all come from only one primary source, the US government?

Comment: @KeithMcClary This source says the British monitored the transmission https://books.google.com/books?id=jp2mZr7BoGsC&pg=PT450&lpg=PT450&dq=%22monitoring+service%22+%22wherever+you+find+them%22&source=bl&ots=BVanTVX5Ti&sig=JDTXnTYz_YYuDgYQSTCeFAPKT68&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY3O-fkOjSAhUESyYKHYkGAoEQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22monitoring%20service%22%20%22wherever%20you%20find%20them%22&f=false  For the US, it was the Foreign Broadcast Monitoring Service of Federal Communications Commission.  So it sounds like two sources, but I can't guarantee.

Comment: Did he *actually* say "Jews" - or did he say something like "infidels", "pagans" or "idolators"; and this was then *interpreted* to mean Jews?  Because the quote seems very close to the "Sword verse" - sure 009.005 of the Koran - and that isn't about Jews and Christians (since they're both "People of the Book), but about "idolators" - people who worship "graven images" (which the Ten Commandments of the Bible also forbids).  And not all idolators, only those that's been allowed into a muslim country from a country that's suddenly turned unfriendly.

Comment: @BaardKopperud I don't have any more information about this particular quote.  Separately, in a pamphlet he wrote for the 13th SS Handzar division he included the quote "The Day of Judgement will come, when the Muslims will crush the Jews completely: And when every tree behind which a Jew hides will say: 'There is a Jew behind me, Kill him!".  https://books.google.com/books?id=97ChE9yj_eQC&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD That's actually from a prophecy. Read more about it here: https://yaqeeninstitute.org/en/nazir-khan/the-myth-of-an-antisemitic-genocide-in-muslim-scripture/#ftnt1